# Split Attribute using ; as delimiter in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How to split an elements using ; as delimiter.my requirement is like below.

input:

```
<Element1>C:KEK39519US; U:085896395195; A:K39519US; B:S2345843</Element1>
```

output:

```
<CustItem>KEK39519US</CustItem>

<UNumber>085896395195</UNumber>

<ANumber>K39519US</ANumber>

<BNumber>S2345843</BNumber>
```

the input is every time not same.some times it comes like `C:KEK39519US; U:085896395195;  B:S2345843` 
some time like this `C:KEK39519US;  A:K39519US; B:S2345843`
sometime like this `U:085896395195; A:K39519US;` 
sometime like this `C:KEK39519US; U:085896395195; A:K39519US;`

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this in XSLT 1.0 you may need a named template which recursively calls itself. The template will process of the string before the first semi-colon, and output the element accordingly. It will then recursively call itself with the remaining part of the string after this semi-colon (if there is one)

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Element1">
      <xsl:call-template name="outputElements">
         <xsl:with-param name="list" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="outputElements">
      <xsl:param name="list"/>

      <xsl:variable name="first" select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($list, ';'), ';'))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="normalize-space(substring-after($list, ';'))"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="createElement">
         <xsl:with-param name="element" select="$first" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <!-- If there are still elements left in the list, call the template recursively -->
      <xsl:if test="$remaining">
         <xsl:call-template name="outputElements">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="createElement">
      <xsl:param name="element"/>
      <xsl:variable name="elementName">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-before($element, ':') = 'C'">CustItem</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($element, ':'), 'Number')" /></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($element, ':')" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML, the following is output

```
<CustItem>KEK39519US</CustItem>
<UNumber>085896395195</UNumber>
<ANumber>K39519US</ANumber>
<BNumber>S2345843</BNumber>
```

Note the use of Attribute Value Templates in specifying the name of each new element.